# How to more easily write !bool in const generics when calling functions?

Tags: rust, const-generics

I have code similar to the following:

```rust
fn f1<const B: bool>(x:u64) { }

fn f2<const B: bool>(x:u64) {
    match B {
        true => f1::<false>(x),
        false => f1::<true>(x),
    }
}
```

That is, I need to negate a const `bool` in function calls. Rust currently doesn't support something as plain as `f1::<!B>()` unfortunately. Is there a better way for me to do this other than to litter `match` statements everywhere?

Comment: you could write a macro

Comment: With `bool`s an `if` statement seems more appropriate, but I doubt that's what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

If this is just one function, I would create a function:

```rust
fn negate_f1<const B: bool>(x: u64) {
    match B {
        true => f1::<false>(x),
        false => f1::<true>(x),
    }
}

fn f2<const B: bool>(x: u64) {
    negate_f1::<B>(x);
}
```

If more, you can create a macro. The following macro works only for bare identifiers (`foo()`, not `foo::bar()`) and one generic parameter, extending it is difficult but possible:

```rust
macro_rules! negate {
    ( $fn:ident :: < ! $param:ident > ( $($arg:expr),* $(,)? ) ) => {
        match $param {
            true => $fn::<false>( $($arg),* ),
            false => $fn::<true>( $($arg),* ),
        }
    }
}

fn f2<const B: bool>(x: u64) {
    negate!(f1::<!B>(x));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On nightly, this can be achieved by enabling the `generic_const_exprs` feature and wrapping the constant expression in curly braces: `f1::<{!B}>`. However due to [this bug](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/80976) this requires extra bounds on `f2`:

```
#![feature(generic_const_exprs)]

fn f1<const B: bool>(_x:u64) { }

pub fn f2<const B: bool>(x:u64) where [(); !B as usize]: {
    f1::<{!B}>(x);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=de431a447fc97a40914faca193689436)